# nginx - how to use 'try_files' and an 'index' statement in the same directory?

Tags: nginx

Both `landing.php` and all the other pages of my site are in the same directory. I want to be able to access both, however if I have a `try_files` statement as *well* as an `index` statement, I get a `404 error` when accessing the index page.

Is there a way to achieve this without conflicting either?

Here's my configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/mysite.com/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/mysite/public/_main;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;

    location / {
            index landing.php;
            try_files $uri $uri.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
            fastcgi_index landing.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally worked out how to do this. What you need is two location blocks, like this:

```
location = / {
     index landing.php;
}

location / {
     try_files $uri $uri.php?$query_string;
}
```

What this does is use `try_files` for any other page such as `www.site.com/somepage`; however if the URL is `www.site.com`, it will fetch the index page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following config it worked for me:

```
server {
    root /path/to/root;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name subdomain.domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```